# How can I make a Flash shape's (x,y) coordinate relate to not its starting point, but its location on the frame

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-builder, flash-cs5

Alright, so I've been struggling with this one since last night. When I create a new object (a new unit), and draw it to the screen (Flash does all the work there), the point at which it's first placed is considered its origin. That is, getX and getY will return the distance from that point...

Why is that? Or how can I stop this?

```
function createUnit(health:int, attack:int, reach:int, speed:int, friendly:Boolean, type:String):Object {
    var unit = new Object();
    unit.cHealth = health;
    unit.tHealth = health;
    unit.uAttack = attack;
    unit.uReach = reach;
    unit.uSpeed = speed;
    if (friendly) {
        unit.xSpeed = -speed;
    } else {
        unit.xSpeed = speed;
    }
    unit.ySpeed = 0;
    unit.isFriendly = friendly;
    unit.unitType = type;
    unit.updateUnit = function() {
        if (unit.cHealth <= 0) {
            deleteUnit(unit);
        }
        unit.moveUnit();
        unit.findClosestUnit();
    }
    unit.getY = function():int {
        return unit.shape.y;
    }
    unit.getX = function():int {
        return unit.shape.x;
    }
    unit.moveUnit = function() {
        unit.shape.x += unit.xSpeed;
        unit.shape.y += unit.ySpeed;
    }
    unit.findClosestUnit = function() {
        var dist:int = 0;
        var closestDist:int = 0;
        var closestUnit:Object = null;
        var array:Array;
        if (unit.isFriendly) {
            array = eUnits;
        } else {
            array = fUnits;
        }

        if (array != null) {
            var i:int = 0;
            for (i; i < array.length; i++) {
                var obj = array[i];
                trace(this.shape.x);
                dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(obj.getX() + unit.getX(), 2) + Math.pow(obj.getY() + unit.getY(), 2));
                //trace(dist);

                if (dist <= closestDist) {
                    closestDist = dist;
                    closestUnit = obj;
                    //basically the two lines below *will* start the unit's movement towards the nearest enemy. 
                    //unit.ySpeed = (unit.getY() - closestUnit.getY())/unit.uSpeed;
                    //unit.xSpeed = (unit.getX() - closestUnit.getX())/unit.uSpeed;
                }

                if (dist <= unit.reach) {
                    unit.attackUnit(closestUnit);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    unit.attackUnit = function(unit2:Object) {
        unit2.cHealth -= unit.attack;
    }

    var spawnX:int;
    var spawnY:int;
    var color:uint;

    if (friendly) {
        spawnX = stage.stageWidth;
        spawnY = stage.stageHeight / 2;
        color = 0xFFCC00;
    } else {
        spawnX = 0;
        spawnY = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
        color = 0x682388;
    }

    var tShape:Shape = new Shape();
    tShape.graphics.beginFill(color);
    tShape.graphics.lineStyle(2, 2);
    tShape.graphics.drawCircle(spawnX, spawnY, 10);
    tShape.graphics.endFill();
    stage.addChild(tShape);
    unit.shape = tShape;

    return unit;
}
```

Comment: Have you read about [Object Oriented Programming](http://www.adobe.com/products/catalog.html)?

Comment: That's kind of what I'm doing... I started flash yesterday but have a background in Java.

Comment: Java is heavy OOP as is AS3 why would you nest functions like this. Your scope will be insanely difficult to manage. You might want to look into document class to get yourself started down the proper route. No offense but this coding style is horrendous. Because you didn't follow standard OOP I doubt you will get an answer. And just so you know origin is generally the top left corner of the bounding box that contains the element you are looking for.

Comment: Oh I know it's horrendous, I started it without looking into class functionality in AS3. Correct me if I'm wrong, but since I'm adding each shape as a child of the stage, their (x,y) coords should be in relation to the top left corner, as you said, of the **stage**.

Answer (score 0):

Shape is a DisplayObject the same as Sprite, MovieClip, and Button. All display objects in flash automatically initialize their X and Y positions when they are created at 0,0.

When you make drawing calls to shape.graphics, the coordinates are relative to the shape's origin. In other words, the shape has its own transform.

To fix your code, change this line:

```
tShape.graphics.drawCircle(spawnX, spawnY, 10);
```

to:

```
tShape.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 10);
```

so that the circle is drawn with its center at the Shape's origin, 0,0.

Then set the shape's position using

```
tShape.x = spawnX; 
tShape.y = spawnY;
```

From there you code will work as expected.

As an aside, Actionsript gains a performance improvement from using strict typing, though it is not required. The choice of using an Object for you Unit may be worth revisiting later in the project when you refactor, and convert it from a generic object to a custom class type. Using object won't break your game, but creating a Type for it may improve your game performance, if you game needs extra performance.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't really done much with Shapes in Flash with as3 but I have done a lot with movieclips.  This seems like the object you should be using.  I would suggest trying to use a movieclip instead of a Shape and see if you are still having the same problem. (Only use movieclip if you will end up needing all of the features that come with it since it is the heaviest DisplayObject).

The other thing I see is that you aren't ever setting the shapes location.  You are always setting the location of the shape to be 0,0 (by never specifying it).  You should do

```
tShape.x = spawnX;
tShape.y = spawnY;
```

And then just draw your circle at 0,0 in the shape.  The drawCircle command draws at the x,y values inside your shape which has its own position.

Comment: `MovieClip` is the most heavyweight `DisplayObject` and shouldn't be recommended unless all of its features are required such as having a timeline and being able to contain children. Visit [this previous answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131078/flash-movieclips-graphics-buttons/8131171#8131171) to see what I mean.

Comment: Based on what he is doing with spawning i'm guessing he is eventually going to want most of these features and not just a circle... But in case not I've edited my answer to make sure that is clear

Comment: Personally I think the OP is to new to flash and really needs to learn the basics. As the question stated getY and getX are returning the distance from the origin. In that "function" he is calling ".x" and ".y" that is the current location of the shape no idea where the distance thought would come from. So yeah good luck but there no correct answer on this question.